# Find starting character(s) in a String

Tags: regex

I am new to RegEx and need to come up with a RegEx that will find matching character(s) in a String.

The possible strings that i could get are:

```
DFG2344KG
4GGRTE
7TTRRE
T89FGFGD
```

So what i want is a RegEx that will check to see if the string starts with **DFG** or **4** or **7** or **T**

I came up with the following.

```
^[DFG|T|7|4]
```

The problem with above RegEx is, even if the string starts with **F** or **G** it will consider it to match, rather than looking for all characters like **DFG**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `[]` with `()`. `[xyz]` matches a single character that's either `x`, `y`, or `z`. `(abc|def|ghi)` matches either `abc`, `def`, or `ghi`. So it should be:

```
^(DFG|[T47])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the group construct, not the range:

```
^(DFG|T|7|4)
```

Comment: @hwnd Thanks, couldn't recall the exact name.

Answer (score 1):

Classes `[]` are for include characters (singular). What you're trying is looking for a D, F or G (not those in succession). You want something like:

```
^(DFG|T|7|4)
```

The pipe (`|`) alternates between the options. Also, given the 2nd, 3rd and 4th option are singular characters you can use a class within a group. e.g.

```
^(DEF|[T74])
```

Both perform the same comparison.

more info:

- [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (aka Character Sets)
- [Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)